# Validation for dropdowns created dynamically using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have few dynamic dropdowns that the created on change of a dropdownlist, on submit of addbutton I need to make sure that none of the dynamic dropdowns are empty. The default value of dynamic dropdowns is empty.

I tried the code below , but it does'nt seem to get the selected value of the dropdown.

```
 DropDownList MynewDdlList = new DropDownList();
 ddllist.ID = "ddl" + name;
 ddllist.Width = 100;
 ddllist.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
 ddllist.Attributes.Add("IsMandatory", "Y");
```

Below is my javascript function

```
function validateInput() {
var ddlTextBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
 var returnValue = 1;

for (j = 0; j < ddlTextBox.length; j++) {
    if (ddlTextBox[j].type =="text" && ddlTextBox[j].getAttribute("IsMandatory")=="Y" && ddlTextBox[j].selectedIndex == "") {
        returnValue = 0;
    }
}
if (returnValue == 0) {
    alert("Validation Failed");
    return false;
}
else {
    alert("Validation Success");
    return true;
}
}
         Please help me with the correct syntax for this  ddlTextBox[j].selectedIndex == "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.selectedIndex` return a number, while `.value` returns a string.  You want either `ddlTextBox[j].selectedIndex == 0` or `ddlTextBox[j].value== ""`

This assumes that your first option index is the empty value.

Comment: I tried if (ddlTextBox[j].type == "text" && ddlTextBox[j].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && (ddlTextBox[j].value == "" || ddlTextBox[j].selectedIndex ==0)) , even though the dropdown box is empty it gives validation success

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used it this way if (ddlTextBox[j].getAttribute("IsMandatory") == "Y" && (ddlTextBox[j].value == "" || ddlTextBox[j].selectedIndex ==0)) { returnValue = 0; }

Comment: I have another doubt pertaining to teh same context...Instead of getting Validation Failed message, how do I get the message with the list of all the controls that did not pass the validation..Can you help me with that?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to do _something_ when a specific control fails validation (in the if statement where you're setting returnValue = 0).  You could either concatenate a string with the ID of the failed control, or do something to that control on failure (such as give it a class `failed` which turns the text red)